# Rails gem for tennis court bookings?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, rubygems

I would like a page, `/bookings` to display a table with three columns, headed "Time", "Court One" and "Court Two". The time column would contain every hour timeslot the current day from "7 to 8 am" to "9 to 10 pm".

All the other cells would either show the current booking in that timeslot for that court, or say "Book now" and when clicked book that court for that timeslot with the current Devise user.

If no user is logged in, it should redirect to the login page. A user can only delete his or her own reservations, unless they are the administrator. (I don't expect the gem to do this though, I can do that.)

Here is a visual:

[image: Table]

I understand that I will have to implement some of this functionality myself, but is there a Rails gem that would get me the closest? I feel this is probably a fairly common task.

I have tried [bookable](https://github.com/kunks001/bookable), but it seemed like it would take longer to get it to work as described above than to start from scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you intend this to be public facing or not, but this seems like a pretty basic application specific task. I would start from scratch on it.

If you're looking for a more general gem that can help you manage models in a generic way, you can checkout [activeadmin](http://activeadmin.info/) or [rails_admin](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin) to help get admin pages quickly.

However, if this is a core, public facing piece of your project, I'd start from scratch. It's not complex enough to get wins by importing someone else's code.

Comment: It will be public facing, however only members of the tennis club will have be able to create a user account and hence be able to reserve a court.

Comment: @duncan I'll be shocked if you find a gem that fulfills your needs precisely.  Especially when you've already decided that configuring the booking gem looks like it'd be more difficult than building something that only does what you need it to do. Do it from scratch! :)

Comment: Alright, I thought there may be a gem that gets me part of the way but it looks like there isn't.